# How to buy English books in iOS Books app from Spain?

Tags: ios, books

I would like to buy books in English in the Books app from Spain. I set phone location to USA and changed system language to English but still can't. Is there any workaround to do this? Would be possible buying a second hand IPhone from the UK/USA?

Comment: Can‘t you find english titles if you search for them in Books Store?

Comment: Yes @nohillside♦, thanks. Can I turn my location back to Spain?

Comment: The audiobook I'm looking for is 5€ cheaper in Play Books

Comment: @biotech you can change the location back, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for book titles in English even though in Spain and can change your location back to the original.

For example, I’m in the UK and if I search for a French title French books come up.

If other stores have it cheaper, you can buy it there.  They all have reader apps for iOS and macOS.